# API Jena - Get values of data properties

Tags: java, awt, rdf, jena, owl

I created an interface in java with 4 labels, 4 textfields and some buttons like "Add", "modify, "next", etc. The user will enter name, first name, birth date, etc. After clicking the button "add", the information that he has entered will be added on rdf file. I'm using API Jena. The "next" (in french "Suivant") button does not work. When i click "Next", nothing appears on textfields. I don't understand why. Can you explain me what's wrong?

#### Complete Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*; 
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.RDF;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.XSD;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.ExtendedIterator;


public class FamilyModel extends Frame
{   
TextField[]tabTF=new TextField[4];
Button bAjout, bModifier, bSupprimer, bPrecedent, bSuivant;
OntModel model;
Onto onto;

Button creerBouton(String S, int x, int y)
{
    Button b=new Button(S);
    add(b);         
    b.setBounds(x,y,120,30);
    return b;
}

void creerLabel(String etiquette, int x, int y)
{
    Label la=new Label(etiquette);
    la.setBounds(x,y,100,25);
    add(la);
}


public FamilyModel ()
{
        setLayout (null);
        setBackground (Color.pink);
        setBounds (100,200,600,450);

        creerLabel("Prenom : ",10,50);
        creerLabel("Nom : ",10,100);
        creerLabel("Date de Naissance: ",10,145);
        creerLabel("Genre (H ou F): ",10,190);

        //TextFields
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            tabTF[i]=new TextField("");
            tabTF[i].setBackground(Color.white);
            add(tabTF[i]);
        }
        tabTF[0].setBounds(120,45,150,25);
        tabTF[1].setBounds(120,100,150,25);
        tabTF[2].setBounds(120,145, 100,25);
        tabTF[3].setBounds(120,190, 45,25);

        bAjout=creerBouton("Ajouter",20,250); 
        setVisible(true);

        bModifier=creerBouton("Modifier",138,250); 
        setVisible(true);

        bSupprimer=creerBouton("Supprimer",250,250); 
        setVisible(true);

        bPrecedent=creerBouton("Precedent",360,250); 

        bSuivant=creerBouton("Suivant",450,250); 
        setVisible(true);   

        onto = new Onto();

        readFileRDF();

        traitement(this); 


}



void traitement(Frame fenetre)
{

    bAjout.addActionListener(new ActionAjoutPersonne());
    bSuivant.addActionListener(new ActionSuivant());
}


//Button Add
public class ActionAjoutPersonne implements ActionListener
{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {

        Resource p1 = onto.model.createResource(onto.uriBase+tabTF[0].getText());


        p1.addProperty(onto.aPourPrenom, tabTF[0].getText());         
        p1.addProperty(onto.aPourNom, tabTF[1].getText());         
        p1.addProperty(onto.aDateNaiss, tabTF[2].getText()); 

        if (tabTF[3].getText().equals("F"))
        {
            p1.addProperty(onto.aGenre, tabTF[3].getText()); 
            p1.addProperty(RDF.type, onto.femme);
        }
        else if (tabTF[3].getText().equals("H"))
        {
            p1.addProperty(onto.aGenre, tabTF[3].getText());    
            p1.addProperty(RDF.type, onto.homme);
        }

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        onto.model.write(sw, "RDF/XML-ABBREV");
        String owlCode = sw.toString();
        File file = new File("d:/Onto1.rdf");
        try{
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
            fw.write(owlCode);
            fw.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
            fnfe.printStackTrace();} 
        catch(IOException ioe){
                ioe.printStackTrace();
        }                
    }
}



public void readFileRDF(){
     String inputFile="D:/Onto1.rdf";
     try{
     InputStream in =new  FileInputStream(inputFile);
      if (in == null) {  
      System.out.println("File not found");
     }  
      onto.model.read(in," ");

     }catch(Exception e) {
           System.out.println("model.read catched error: " + e);
     }
}

//Button Next
class ActionSuivant implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {

        readFileRDF();

        //Instances Classe Personne    
        ExtendedIterator instances=onto.personne.listInstances();


        while (instances.hasNext())
            {

                 Individual thisInstance = (Individual) instances.next();
                 thisInstance.getLocalName();

                 {

                   tabTF[0].setText((thisInstance.getPropertyValue(onto.aPourPrenom)).toString());
                   tabTF[1].setText((thisInstance.getPropertyValue(onto.aPourNom)).toString());
                   tabTF[2].setText((thisInstance.getPropertyValue(onto.aDateNaiss)).toString());
                   tabTF[3].setText((thisInstance.getPropertyValue(onto.aGenre)).toString());
                 }
                 System.out.println("Hello-Apres If");                 
             }
         }
    }


//ontologie
public class Onto 
{
    OntClass personne, genre, homme, femme, feminin, masculin, evenement, deces, mariage, divorce;
    OntModel model;
    String uriBase;
    ObjectProperty aPourFils, aPourFille, aGenre;
    DatatypeProperty aPourNom, aPourPrenom, aDateNaiss;

    public Onto (){
    model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM);
    uriBase = "http://www.something.com/FAM";
    model.createOntology(uriBase);

    //Classes
    personne = model.createClass(uriBase+"#personne");
    femme = model.createClass(uriBase+"#femme");
    homme = model.createClass(uriBase+"#homme");
    genre = model.createClass(uriBase+"#genre");
    feminin = model.createClass(uriBase+"#feminin");
    masculin = model.createClass(uriBase+"#masculin");
    evenement = model.createClass(uriBase+"#evenement");
    deces = model.createClass(uriBase+"#deces");
    mariage = model.createClass(uriBase+"#mariage");
    divorce = model.createClass(uriBase+"#divorce");


    //Sous-classes
    genre.addSubClass(feminin);
    genre.addSubClass(masculin);
    personne.addSubClass(homme);
    personne.addSubClass(femme);
    evenement.addSubClass(deces);
    evenement.addSubClass(mariage);
    evenement.addSubClass(divorce);

    aPourFils = model.createObjectProperty(uriBase+"#aPourFils");
    aPourFils.setDomain(personne);
    aPourFils.setRange(homme);

    aPourFille = model.createObjectProperty(uriBase+"#aPourFille");
    aPourFille.setDomain(personne);
    aPourFille.setRange(femme);

    aGenre = model.createObjectProperty(uriBase+"#aGenre");
    aGenre.setDomain(personne);
    aGenre.setRange(genre);

    aPourNom = model.createDatatypeProperty(uriBase+"#aPourNom"); 
    aPourNom.setDomain(personne);
    aPourNom.setRange(XSD.xstring);

    aPourPrenom = model.createDatatypeProperty(uriBase+"#aPourPrenom"); 
    aPourPrenom.setDomain(personne);
    aPourPrenom.setRange(XSD.xstring);

    aDateNaiss = model.createDatatypeProperty(uriBase+"#aDateNaiss"); 
    aDateNaiss.setDomain(personne);
    aDateNaiss.setRange(XSD.xstring);
    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) 
{

    new FamilyModel();      
}
}
```

**Onto.rdf file:**

```
<rdf:RDF
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
xmlns:j.0="http://www.something.com/FAM#"
xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.something.com/FAM"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.something.com/FAM#divorce">
<rdfs:subClassOf>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.something.com/FAM#evenement"/>
</rdfs:subClassOf>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.something.com/FAM#masculin">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.something.com/FAM#genre"/>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.something.com/FAM#deces">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.something.com/FAM#evenement"/>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.something.com/FAM#feminin">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.something.com/FAM#genre"/>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.something.com/FAM#mariage">
     <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.something.com/FAM#evenement"/>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.something.com/FAM#femme">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.something.com/FAM#personne"/>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.something.com/FAM#homme">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.something.com/FAM#personne"/>
   </owl:Class>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.something.com/FAM#aGenre">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.something.com/FAM#genre"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.something.com/FAM#personne"/>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.something.com/FAM#aPourFille">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.something.com/FAM#femme"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.something.com/FAM#personne"/>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.something.com/FAM#aPourFils">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.something.com/FAM#homme"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.something.com/FAM#personne"/>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.something.com/FAM#aPourNom">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.something.com/FAM#personne"/>
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.something.com/FAM#aDateNaiss">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.something.com/FAM#personne"/>
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.something.com/FAM#aPourPrenom">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.something.com/FAM#personne"/>
   </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <j.0:femme rdf:about="http://www.something.com/FAMRita">
    <j.0:aGenre>F</j.0:aGenre>
    <j.0:aDateNaiss>Mars</j.0:aDateNaiss>
    <j.0:aPourNom>Henriques</j.0:aPourNom>
    <j.0:aPourPrenom>Rita</j.0:aPourPrenom>
  </j.0:femme>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.something.com/FAMRicardo">
    <j.0:aGenre>H</j.0:aGenre>
    <j.0:aDateNaiss>maio</j.0:aDateNaiss>
    <j.0:aPourNom>Silva</j.0:aPourNom>
    <j.0:aPourPrenom>Ricardo</j.0:aPourPrenom>
  </rdf:Description>
```

Comment: Hard to diagnose without seeing the whole thing - can you post a copy of what's in "D:/Onto1.rdf"? Without that we can't tell what problems ActionSuivant may have with the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, here's what is happening. When a user hits the `Suivant` button, the action listener reads the contents of the `Onto1.rdf` file, and attempts to populate the form with RDF values for resources of `rdf:type` `http://www.something.com/FAM#personne`. In that RDF file, there are two resources including `...#FAMRita` of `rdf:type` `http://www.something.com/FAM#femme`. Since `#femme` is a sub-type (ie `rdfs:subClassOf`) `#personne`, it's reasonable for you to expect that listing instance of the personne `OntClass` will return the `FAMRita` instance.

However, that doesn't happen, which is why you don't get your form fields filled in. The reason is this:

```
public Onto() {
    model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM );
```

In Jena, the `OntModel`s made with a `xxx_MEM` profile specifically have no reasoning turned on. This means that the model does **not** infer that `#FAMRita` also has type `#personne`, hence it not returned by the `listInstances` iterator.

The easy fix is this:

```
public Onto() {
    model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF );
```

which means that you will get inference, and Rita will show up.

Comment: I put System.out.println() on each parameter I pass to the tabTF[i].setText(), to see what's being printed. There are 2 instances in the rf file, and when button Next is pressed, it shows in console the information regarding the 2 instances at the same time. 1 click, 2 instances...not only 1 as I expected. And when I clicked again on Next it returns again the 2 instances information.
I edited my topic to add my code updated. Can you tell me what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Actually, it would be better if you had not done this. StackOverflow tries to collect together a set of good answers to specific questions. Once you have a good-enough answer to the question, you should mark it as 'accepted' so that other users can find this answer in future. If you have a new question, even if it's related to a previous discussion, you should post a new top-level question to stackoverflow.

Comment: Excuse-me Ian. I removed what i had added and I posted a new top-level question.

Comment: Thank you! I see that you have now got a good answer to the other question. If you feel that the answers you have received have solved your problem, please 'accept' them by clicking on the grey tick symbol next to your preferred answer (on the left). This helps other users find a good solution if they have a similar problem.